# How to fix an "Invalid Character in Path" Error, When downloading a File and named by its title

Tags: c#, .net, video, download, character

I'm getting an Invalid Character In Path error, I know Why I am, My Code is giving the file name based off a title of a video, and the video Has an invalid character to Be specific it's this character "|" From this video
'GLORYHAMMER - Angus McFife " | " Napalm Records' I just need to know how to fix it. I'm using the YoutubeExtractor plugin.

```
private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;
    IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(txtUrl.Text);
    VideoInfo video = videos.First(p => p.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && p.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(cboResolution.Text));
    if (video.RequiresDecryption) 
    {
        DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
    }
    VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));
    downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged;
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => { downloader.Execute(); }) { IsBackground = true };
    thread.Start();
}
```

I had done a few things like doing an if statement

```
if (video.Title.Contains("/"))
{
    video.Title.Replace("/", "");
}
```

or using Regex but I quickly figured out that wasn't going to work because I needed a KeyPush Event. I'm using a download event, and its extracting the title which contains the Illegal Character.

If yall could help with this, I'd be so grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a snippet I have for creating a "safe" file name:

```
internal static string GetSafeFileName(string fromString, char usingSafeReplacementChar)
{
    var invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();

    if (invalidChars.Contains(usingSafeReplacementChar))
        throw new System.ArgumentException(
        string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid safe replacement character.", 
        usingSafeReplacementChar));

    return new string(fromString.Select((inputChar) =>
        invalidChars.Any((invalidChar) =>
        (inputChar == invalidChar)) ? usingSafeReplacementChar : inputChar).ToArray());
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
string newName = GetSafeFileName(video.Title, '_');
```

Comment: string newName = GetSafeFileName(video.Title, '_'); Thanks but where would i put

Comment: In the line right above `VideoDownloader downloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath + "\\", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));`.  Make sure you change `video.Title` in *this* line to `newName`.  Alternatively, you could just put it all in that one line (thought I'm not a fan of doing too many things in one statement).

Comment: YAHOOOO Thank you so much. Been up since 3 and you made it so much easier for me!